# Частичный поиск по id

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как сделать, чтобы sql запрос позволял бы искать частично по id?

У меня есть такой код:

```
return cFactory::getDB()->getRows("
        SELECT TOP 20
            ID_Order,
            ID_Contact
        FROM
            tblOrder
        WHERE
            ID_Contact IS NOT NULL
            AND ID_Order = ''
    ", __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

Но как правильно написать `WHERE` с `ID_Order` если `like` можно использовать только для строковых значений?

Comment: CONVERT(ID_Order, char) LIKE '%9%'

Comment: @MaxDown боюсь char будет маловат у меня там числа по 9 символов, а так я почти до такого же дошел только использую CAST

Comment: Что значит "искать частично по id"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перечитал документацию MS SQL, работает даже так:

```
return cFactory::getDB()->getRows("
    SELECT TOP 20
        ID_Order,
        ID_Contact
    FROM
        tblOrder
    WHERE
        ID_Contact IS NOT NULL
        AND ID_Order LIKE '" . $search . "%'
    ", __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

Comment: Если искать надо первым цифрам номера заказа, то имеет смысл сделат отдельное текстовое поле с дублем номера, повесить на него индекс и искать как `code like 'xxx%`. Если искать как `%xxx%` то смысла в этом нет.

Comment: @teran Тут я с вами соглашусь. Кстати без отдельного поля тоже нормально ищет, не очень быстро, но учитывая, что фрон на vuejs пользователь не особо жалуется, учитывая, что это еще и админка.